# How to scale axes independently in pyvista?

Tags: python, 3d, scale, pyvista

Suppose I have `x`, `y`, `z` and `x2`, `y2`, `z2` arrays. I am plotting them as 2 different 3d splines in pyvista.

```
import numpy as np
import pyvista as pv

network = pv.MultiBlock()

points_1 = np.column_stack((x, y, z))
spline_1 = pv.Spline(points_1, 500).tube(radius=0.1)

points_2 = np.column_stack((x2, y2, z2))
spline_2 = pv.Spline(points_2, 500).tube(radius=0.1)

network.append(spline_1)
network.append(spline_2)

p = pv.Plotter()
labels = dict(zlabel='l1', xlabel='l2', ylabel='l2')
p.show_grid(**labels)
p.add_axes(**labels)
p.add_mesh(spline_1, color="red", line_width=3)
p.add_mesh(spline_2, color="blue", line_width=3)
```

The problem of this plot is that one axis is too compressed: `y` axis values are around 300 whereas `x` axis range from 0 to 20. It seems the plot uses the same scale for all axis. Furthermore, `x` and `y` are different quantity so I don't want to compare them.

`Matplotlib` for example automatically scales the axes and to use the same scale on, for example, `y` and `x` axes you do `ax.set_aspect("equalxy")`.

In this case axes are already scaled and I want to make one use a different size. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

PyVista plots in physical cartesion space, so you'll need to set the scale on the scene with `pl.set_scale()` See docs: https://docs.pyvista.org/version/stable/api/plotting/_autosummary/pyvista.Plotter.set_scale.html#pyvista.Plotter.set_scale